# Java Bitstamp API market order File not Found

Tags: java, android, rest, api, http-post

I am trying to make a post from Java to make a market order using my Bitstamp account but the following code is returning a file not found for the URL.

It may be because of CSRF but I am unsure, if anyone has had any experience with the bitstamp API that would be great.

```
public static void postToken() throws IOException, JSONException {
    URL url = null;
    String sig = encode();
    try {
        url = new URL("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/buy/market/" + feedbackType.toLowerCase() +"usd/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);//5 secs
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);//5 secs

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        JSONObject cred = new JSONObject();

        cred.put("key",api_key);
        cred.put("signature", sig);
        cred.put("nonce", nonce);
        cred.put("amount", feedback);

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(cred.toString());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        int res = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(res);

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, line);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/buy/market/btcusd/

Comment: Well click on the url link you posted...

Comment: `out.close();` Remove that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, removing out.close did not work.

What do you mean by the link? It's a post endpoint, I am trying to send a post..

Comment: You posted the url isnt it? If i click on it it reaches the server and complains that it is a post endpont only.

Comment: Why is that a problem? That is the URL I am trying to make the post call to?

Comment: If it exists .. then why do you get a file not found exception i would say. And why didnt you tell that the url was valid?

Comment: Try to use `HttpsUrlConnection` instead.

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny but that's kind of what I am asking I can't seem to figure it out. I will do, thanks!